# testcafe: report the page HTML on any assertion failure

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

is there a way to make testcafe report the page's html when an assertion fails, regardless of the reason? This information would be helpful in a lot of situations where you're not sure why the test failed and it only gives limited information like this:

```
1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

      | Selector('button')
    > |   .withText('Foo')
```

That could occur for any number of reasons, including not being on the page I think I'm on.

Ideally, there would be a way of setting this up in advance instead of changing every single assertion I've already written, but if there is a way of changing this assertion to give me the HTML content, that would be better than where I'm at: When I run through this test by hand, that button is there.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom reporter, which reports html code of a page when the assertion failed. For that, check the following guide: [Reporter Plugin](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/extend-testcafe/reporter-plugin.html).
TestCafe Community created a bunch of useful reporters, so it is likely that such a reporter has already been written by someone. Search them on the NPM registry: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=testcafe-reporter

Although, a more common practice to approach issues with missing elements on a page is to examine the page's source code in [Debug mode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/debug.html).

Comment: I have read all of that documentation before and I don't see a way of achieving what I'm asking for.  Can you provide example code that would report the html on the page when the error occurred?

Comment: I've realized that now it can be achieved only with the limitation when your page doesn't change during the test. You should iterate through the `errs` property of the `testRunInfo` object argument in the `reportTestDone` [method](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/plugin-api/reporter.html#reporttestdone), and use the URL specified by the [Test.meta](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/test/meta.html) method to fetch the HTML code of the page in a custom way.

Comment: Currently, it's the only way to pass custom data to the reporter. I've added your use case to the related feature suggestion: [Sending custom data to reporter](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3584).

Comment: debug mode isn't very helpful unless it's possible to wrap a conditional around an assertion: "debug if it fails." This doesn't fail every time, it fails randomly. And my tests are ten times faster in headless mode so they always run that way.